# How to replace all escape sequences with non-escaped equivalent with unix utilities (sed/tr/awk)

Tags: awk, sed, escaping, tr

I'm processing a Wireshark config file (dfilter_buttons) for display filters and would like to print out the filter of a given name.  The content of file is like:

**Sample input**

```
"TRUE","test","sip contains \x22Hello, world\x5cx22\x22",""
```

And the resulting output should have the escape sequences replaced, so I can use them later in my script:

**Desired output**

```
sip contains "Hello, world\x22"
```

My first pass is like this:

**Current parser**

```
filter_name=test
awk -v filter_name="$filter_name" 'BEGIN {FS="\",\""} ($2 == filter_name) {print $3}' "$config_file"
```

And my output is this:

**Current output**

```
sip contains \x22Hello, world\x5cx22\x22
```

I know I can handle these exact two escape sequences by piping to sed and matching those exact two sequences, but is there a generic way to substitutes all escape sequences?  Future filters I build may utilize more escape sequences than just " and , and I would like to handle future scenarios.

Comment: `printf 'sip contains \x22Hello, world\x5cx22\x22\n'` Seems like a good place to start. (Although I believe it is the bash builtin that parses the \x22, and some printf don't handle hex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gnu-awk` you can do this using `split`, `gensub` and `strtonum` functions:

```sh
awk -F '","' -v filt='test' '$2 == filt {n = split($3, subj, /\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}/, seps); for (i=1; i<n; ++i) printf "%s%c", subj[i], strtonum("0" substr(seps[i], 2)); print subj[i]}' file

sip contains "Hello, world\x22"
```

A more readable form:

```sh
awk -F '","' -v filt='test' '
$2 == filt {
   n = split($3, subj, /\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}/, seps)
   for (i=1; i<n; ++i)
      printf "%s%c", subj[i], strtonum("0" substr(seps[i], 2))
   print subj[i]
}' file
```

**Explanation:**

- Using `-F '","'` we split input using delimiter `","`
- `$2 == filt` we filter input for `$2 == "test"` condition
- Using `/\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}/` as regex (that matches 2 digit hex strings) we split `$3` and save split tokens into array `subj` and matched separators into array `seps`
- Using `substr` we remove first char i.e `\\` and prepend `0`
- Using `strtonum` we convert hex string to equivalent ascii number
- Using `%c` in `printf` we print corresponding ascii character
- Last `for` loop joins `$3` back using `subj` and `seps` array elements

Comment: Where does the null character come from?

Comment: @RustyLemur: `seps` array will have one less length than `subj` array and that was the reason of last NUL character. I have fixed it now.

Comment: @RustyLemur FYI `null` is a string, `NUL` is a character.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for FPAT, gensub(), strtonum(), and the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]*\")"; OFS="," }
$2 == ("\"" filter_name "\"") {
    gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$3)
    while ( match($3,/(\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2})(.*)/,a) ) {
        printf "%s%c", substr($3,1,RSTART-1), strtonum(gensub(/./,0,1,a[1]))
        $3 = a[2]
    }
    print $3
}
```

```
$ awk -v filter_name='test' -f tst.awk file
sip contains "Hello, world\x22"
```

The above assumes your escape sequences are always `\x` followed by exactly 2 hex digits. It isolates every `\xHH` string in the input, replaces `\` with `0` in that string so that `strtonum()` can then convert the string to a number, then uses `%c` in the `printf` formatting string to convert that number to a character.

Note that GNU awk has a debugger (see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Debugger) so if you're ever not sure what any part of a program does you can just run it in the debugger (`-D`) and trace it, e.g. in the following I plant a breakpoint to tell awk to stop at line 1 of the script (`b 1`), then start running (`r`) and the step (`s`) through the script printing the value of $3 (`p $3`) at each line so I can see how it changes after the `gsub()`:

```
$ awk -D -v filter_name='test' -f tst.awk file
gawk> b 1
Breakpoint 1 set at file `tst.awk', line 1
gawk> r
Starting program:
Stopping in BEGIN ...
Breakpoint 1, main() at `tst.awk':1
1       BEGIN { FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]*\")"; OFS="," }
gawk> p $3
$3 = uninitialized field
gawk> s
Stopping in Rule ...
2       $2 == "\"" filter_name "\"" {
gawk> p $3
$3 = "\"sip contains \\x22Hello, world\\x5cx22\\x22\""
gawk> s
3           gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$3)
gawk> p $3
$3 = "\"sip contains \\x22Hello, world\\x5cx22\\x22\""
gawk> s
4           while ( match($3,/(\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2})(.*)/,a) ) {
gawk> p $3
$3 = "sip contains \\x22Hello, world\\x5cx22\\x22"
```

Comment: What is the gsub for?

Comment: To remove the quotes at the start and end of the string that is the 3rd `,`-separated field, `"sip contains \x22Hello, world\x5cx22\x22"`, since you don't want it to be quoted in the output. You can add `print` statements to the script to see the values of the fields, variables, etc. before and after any manipulation of them to see what they are and what's happening to them.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks!  I was mistaking the "|" as a literal pipe character, not a logical OR separator.

Comment: @RustyLemur I added some instructions to show how you can use the gawk debugger to see what the values of variables are as you execute the script.